# shiro configuration for integration testsing

Tags: java, shiro

For most of my integration test I don't need any security checks. I just want to have shiro out of my way. Beeing a shiro noob I'm wondering whether there's a better way than the one I found.

In my ShiroFilter class, if authentication fails I added this code:

```
try {
    currentUser.login(token);
    return CONTINUE;
} catch (AuthenticationException e1) {

    // if everything failed, we might actualy have the integration test configuration, let's try
    UsernamePasswordToken testToken = new UsernamePasswordToken("testUser", "testPassword", true, host);
    try {
        currentUser.login(testToken);
        return CONTINUE;
    } catch (AuthenticationException e2) {
        LOGGER.info("Unable to login", e2);
    }

}
```

And this is the shiro.ini for the integration tests:

```
[users]
testUser = testPassword, administrator

[roles]
administrator = *
```

Comment: In our environment there is always a root user created with every right, just like your administrator and at the start of each test we just log in that user. So, quite similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for mock Shiro on integration tests.

```
    package util;

    import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
    import org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException;
    import org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager;
    import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
    import org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectThreadState;
    import org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils;
    import org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadState;
    import org.junit.AfterClass;

    /**
     * Abstract test case enabling Shiro in test environments.
     */
    public abstract class AbstractShiroTest {

        private static ThreadState subjectThreadState;

        public AbstractShiroTest() {
        }

        /**
         * Allows subclasses to set the currently executing {@link Subject} instance.
         *
         * @param subject the Subject instance
         */
        protected void setSubject(Subject subject) {
            clearSubject();
            subjectThreadState = createThreadState(subject);
            subjectThreadState.bind();
        }

        protected Subject getSubject() {
            return SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        }

        protected ThreadState createThreadState(Subject subject) {
            return new SubjectThreadState(subject);
        }

        /**
         * Clears Shiro's thread state, ensuring the thread remains clean for future test execution.
         */
        protected void clearSubject() {
            doClearSubject();
        }

        private static void doClearSubject() {
            if (subjectThreadState != null) {
                subjectThreadState.clear();
                subjectThreadState = null;
            }
        }

        protected static void setSecurityManager(SecurityManager securityManager) {
            SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        }

        protected static SecurityManager getSecurityManager() {
            return SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownShiro() {
            doClearSubject();
            try {
                SecurityManager securityManager = getSecurityManager();
                LifecycleUtils.destroy(securityManager);
            } catch (UnavailableSecurityManagerException e) {
                //we don't care about this when cleaning up the test environment
                //(for example, maybe the subclass is a unit test and it didn't
                // need a SecurityManager instance because it was using only
                // mock Subject instances)
            }
            setSecurityManager(null);
        }
    }
```

Then on test classes that you have Shiro dependency:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ManterCampanhaServiceImplTest extends AbstractShiroTest {

@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    Subject subjectUnderTest = Mockito.mock(Subject.class);
    when(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(EntityObjectMother.getUserData()); //Subject for test
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);

    // Now you have a test with a mock subject

    // Write the test...
}}
```